# NiFi JoltTransformJSON

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

NiFi throws an error in the **JOLT** processor - although the test inside the "advanced" processor interface works flawlessly!

Some flowfiles are converted without error - the majority however fail - eg:

JSON:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "HEADER": {
            "A": "WDD2132041A2213962",
            "B": "75268508"
        },
        "BODY": {
            "C": "OK",
            "D": "1"
        },
        "ABCDEFG": "Time[s]   |  X  |  Y  |  Z  | A/B [%] | X/Y [%] "
    }
}
```

JOLT:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "abc": {
        "HEADER": { "*": "&" },
        "SUMMARY": { "*": "&" },
        "*": { "$": "ITEM", "@": "VAL" }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Did anyone run into this kind of error before?

```
    2017-03-24 15:12:35,765 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.n.p.standard.JoltTransformJSON
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load JSON object from InputStream.
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtilImpl.jsonToObject(JsonUtilImpl.java:105) ~[json-utils-0.0.21.jar:0.0.21]
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils.jsonToObject(JsonUtils.java:117) ~[json-utils-0.0.21.jar:0.0.21]
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON.onTrigger(JoltTransformJSON.java:244) ~[nifi-standard-processors-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27) [nifi-api-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132) [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["xml"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ContainerDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(ContainerDeserializerBase.java:88) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:507) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:341) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:220) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2784) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtilImpl.jsonToObject(JsonUtilImpl.java:102) ~[json-utils-0.0.21.jar:0.0.21]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I believe the stack trace suggests the processor fails to read JSON from your flowfile.  Is the failing flowfile's actual content different from what you pasted above and into the Advanced UI?

Comment: the content has special characters in it - like e.g.   `"1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0"`   but inside ""

Comment: Can you check if it is well-formed JSON by loading it using a different NiFi processor or external tool that parses JSON?  EvaluateJsonPath might work.

Comment: JSON is well formatted - we have not eliminated JOLT and solved the dilemma by adapting xQuery and XSLT

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to reproduce, but I am using the latest source code (which will at some point become NiFi 1.2.0) which has an upgrade of the Jolt library as well as some changes to the JoltTransformJSON processor. I pasted in the JSON above and the spec, and it converted fine.

Is the JSON being passed to JoltTransformJSON using a character set other than the Java default (often UTF-8)? If so, try a [ConvertCharacterSet](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertCharacterSet/index.html) processor before the JoltTransformJSON processor.

Answer (score 1):

Like mattyb I tried this as well and was also unable to reproduce (using the latest source).  If you are able to capture failed content and post , along with the NiFi version you are using, I may be able to at least recreate the problem and investigate from there.